# Is there any Perl Module available to send messages to Office Communicator?

Tags: perl, sip, office-communicator

Is there any Perl module available to send messages to Office Communicator?
I searched in CPAN but without any luck.
Can I use Python or Ruby to send messages to Office Communicator.
I want to do this from a Linux Box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As "Office Communicator" is using a modified version of SIP, you can try using SIP clients like [Net::SIP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SIP) (or [Net::SIP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::SIP::Simple) from same package).

Answer (score 2):

I guess you'll have found a solution after more than a year, but nonetheless, if you just want to send a SIP message writing a perl program, you can have a look at this approach: http://archive.cert.uni-stuttgart.de/bugtraq/2005/07/msg00276.html

A possible customization:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Socket;

sub SendSIPTo {
    my ($from, $to, $text, $ProxyIP) = @_;

    my $contentLength = length($text);

    my $AT = '@';
    my $domain = 'example.com';
    my $ToURI = 'sip:' . $to . $AT . $domain;
    my $FromURI = 'sip:' . $from . $AT . $domain;

    my $MESG = "MESSAGE $ToURI SIP\/2.0\r
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.10.10.10;branch=z9hG4bK8fe6.db5fade4.0\r
To: $ToURI\r
From: <$FromURI>;tag=578c0e59d7504cca4dc4a96522981b0a-0c8b\r
CSeq: 1 MESSAGE\r
Call-ID: 609ded3a79a9cbd5\r
Content-Length: $contentLength\r
User-Agent: perl\r
\r
" . $text;

    my $proto = getprotobyname('udp');
    socket(SOCKET, PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, $proto) ;
    my $iaddr = inet_aton("0.0.0.0");
    my $paddr = sockaddr_in(5060, $iaddr);
    bind(SOCKET, $paddr) ;

    my $port = 5060;
    my $hisiaddr = inet_aton($ProxyIP) ;
    my $hispaddr = sockaddr_in($port, $hisiaddr);
    send(SOCKET, $MESG, 0, $hispaddr ) || warn "send $!\n";

    return 'OK';
}

1;
```